# Ubuntu server 20.04 missing wireds connections in settings

Tags: networking, server, 20.04, network-manager, dell

I cannot find the wireds connection on Ubuntu server 20.04 (DELL PowerEdge 2850)
I have two networks carts.

[Terminal and settings][1]

terminal:  https://prnt.sc/tyujfh
settings:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqSzA.png

I have tried those:

```
$ sudo /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

sudo: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf: command not found

```
    $ sudo /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

sudo: /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml: command not found

and this

```
sudo touch /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf
sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager
```

**cat /etc/network/interfaces and cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml**

```
 https://prnt.sc/tyiyk1
```

Can somebody help me?
Thanks a lot!
Agni

Comment: NetworkManager is normally not used on a Server installation. Netplan is the default. But it looks like you've installed Ubuntu Desktop on top of the Server, yes? Edit your question and show me `cat /etc/network/interfaces` and `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thanks for your quick answer. Yes, I installed it first Ubuntu server and after i I installed the desktop interface. is it good the information I have given you?

Comment: In looking at your recent updates, I see that the first ethernet card does have a valid IP address, but its connection speed is only 100Mbs, instead of 1Gbs. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Describe your network wiring from the back of the computer, all the way to the router/modem.

Comment: the one cable had a problem so i removed it.

Comment: https://prnt.sc/tykrfd

Comment: The interface is still showing 100Mbs. Are you using cat 5e or cat 6 cables? Describe your network wiring from the back of the computer, all the way to the router/modem. Is the entire path 1G?

Comment: @heynnema Hello, I changed today to new cables cat 6.  https://prnt.sc/tyujfh

Comment: The interface is still showing 100Mbs. As requested earlier, please describe your network wiring from computer to router/modem. Is it a 1G path? Which .yaml file did you use?

Answer (score 1):

Edit the .yaml file in /etc/netplan:

```
ls -al /etc/netplan/*.yaml

sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/your_filename.yaml
```

Use ONE of the following:

For `netplan`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp6s7:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
    enp7s8:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
```

For `NetworkManager`:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

---

`sudo netplan generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`